# CKFinder3 sys_get_temp_dir not working in Linux? using apache 2.4 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ckeditor5, ckfinder

I was able to setup working ckeditor/ckfinder plugin on my local

[image]

However when I tried to move the project to AWS ckfinder suddenly is not working anymore.

I suspected it's because on the temp directory on config.php

`$config['tempDirectory'] = sys_get_temp_dir();`

Here's the error on AWS ec2

[image]

**UPDATE**

Invalid Request Error and when I tried to inspect element it says

[image: http://projectdev-ip/labelin/public/_admin/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=Init&lang=en&langCode=en]

Invalid request shows up when I try to click this icon

[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like a **proper** error message. How is that "Invalid request" modal triggered?

Comment: @Nico please see my updated post

Comment: Even you updated post does not contain any error message. If an error 500 is thrown, there is most likely something written to your server's error log. If not, use a higher error reporting level